# ffmpeg command line write output to a text file

Tags: ffmpeg, output, ffprobe

I'm using this script for shot detection in ffmpeg.

```
ffprobe -show_frames -of compact=p=0 -f lavfi "movie=test.mp4,select=gt(scene\,0.3)"
```

I need to write the output into a text file in order to read the output from a c program. How can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You redirect the output to a file:

`ffprobe -show_frames -of compact=p=0 -f lavfi "movie=test.mp4,select=gt(scene\,0.3)" > output.txt 2>&1`

If you want separate files for `stdout` and `stderr` you can do:

`[..] > out.txt 2> err.txt`

Comment: Yes, I remember now this. It was always a mystery to me. Is there any explanation for this weird thing?

Comment: @Apostolos Which weird thing?

Comment: I mean this `2>&1` stuff. Why, do you have an explanation for it?  In **what way** does it solve the problem that the  regular `>file` redirection doesn't work?

Comment: There are two different standard output streams, `stdout` (1) and `stderr` (2) which can be used individually. `>` redirects `stdout` (1) to a file and `2>&1` redirects `stderr` (2) to a copy of the file descriptor used for (1) so both the normal output and errors messages are written to the same file. Some shells have a `&>`  to redirect both standard output streams.

Comment: Thanks.  So, if understand well, '1>' is never used since it's implied (default redirection from `stdout` output). And if just a '>' doesn't work it means that the program -- weirdly enough -- sends output to `stderr`, right?  (I won't ask why so! :))

Comment: @Apostolos it's up to the programmer, you may want to keep normal output separate from error output. Since your top tag is [tag:python], `print("...")` will write to `stdout` and `print("...", file=sys.stderr)` will print to `stderr`.

Comment: Well, when you use `stderr` to print "help" for your program at user request, and the text cannot be captured by the user who normally knows only about **regular** redirection, you are not so wise a programmer, are you?  Fortunately though, most **are** wise! :))

Comment: @Apostolos That's not a good reasoning. In `ffmpeg`'s case stdout might be used for video output in order to pipe it to other processes.