# Load output of ffmpeg command in text file which detects silences

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I load the output of below command into a text file?

**ffmpeg -i units.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-20dB:d=0.2 -f null -**

This command simply detects the silences from a video and I need to store this output in a text file.

I have also found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680391/ffmpeg-command-line-write-output-to-a-text-file) but as I am newbie in ffmpeg I am not able to use it in my command.

Thanks..

Comment: what issues do you have with the answer on that link?

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to post this update for other people who've had this problem. I had the same problem with the > pipe command and found you can use 2> instead. Possible FFMpeg bug? Not sure.

```
ffmpeg -i units.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-20dB:d=0.2 -f null - 2> output.txt
```

Comment: also, you may want to add the `-nostats` option otherwise you will get lots of lines that contain something like "bitrate=N/A speed= 117x" in addition to the output of the silence detector, not even separated by newlines. `ffmpeg -nostats -i units.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-20dB:d=0.2 -f null - 2> output.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe its output to a file like this:

```
ffmpeg -i units.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-20dB:d=0.2 -f null - > output.txt
```

Comment: this is similar to the answer on the linked (duplicate) question, what issues do you have with it?

Comment: I was using the command like this "
ffmpeg -i units.wav -af silencedetect=noise=-20dB:d=0.2 -f nulll - > output.txt 2>&1" and it was doing nothing, no output and no error message. But now I have also used the way you suggested above, command ran successfully and it also generated a text file but the text file is empty.