# How to save the output of an FFmpeg command into a text file

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I save the output of an ffmpeg process into a text file? I see the stuff I want to save come up in the terminal:

```
frame=62 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=0kB time=00:00:01.06 bitrate=0.3kbit
frame=116 fps=115 q=-0.0 size=0kB time=00:00:01.97 bitrate=0.2kbit
frame=175 fps=116 q=-0.0 size=kB time=00:00:02.92 bitrate=0.1kbit
frame=232 fps=113 q=-0.0 size=0kB time=00:00:03.87 bitrate=0.1kbit
```

But need to know how this can be saved into a test file or even a csv file

Comment: Which Operating system are you using? Console output can be redirected to files in many ways. Are you using ffmpeg from a command line? Or inside a code?

Comment: I'm using Mac and using ffmpeg from command line

Comment: The entire log or only the progress lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ffmpeg command line write output to a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680391/ffmpeg-command-line-write-output-to-a-text-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680391/ffmpeg-command-line-write-output-to-a-text-file/29685796