# How to copy ffprobe dumped metadata to a converted video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I hope you're all doing safe! I'm using windows 10 and have lots of home videos, some of them are on `.AVI` format. I just discovered google photos don't backup `.AVI` videos, I tried converting it with GUI converters (FormatFactory, Wondershare, HandBrake) but when I tried to back it up, it wasn't preserving the metadata of my newly converted videos.

I tried further research on this matter and I stumble upon [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org) (w/c the GUIs were using). I successfully converted `.MOV` while preserving metadata using:

```
ffmpeg -i in.MOV -b:v 73000k -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict -2 -map_metadata 0 out.mp4
```

but when I tried converting `.AVI` videos, with the command above, it doesn't retain the original metadata for the `out.mp4`.

I tried another approach and I found out a method of [dumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29680391/ffmpeg-command-line-write-output-to-a-text-file) the metadata on a `.txt` then [restoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706049/converting-video-formats-and-copying-tags-with-ffmpeg) it on the `out.mp4`.

```
ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams DSCF0421.AVI > output.txt 2>&1
```

The command above does save it on the `output.txt`

```
output.txt


[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=mjpeg
codec_long_name=Motion JPEG
profile=Baseline
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=33333/1000000
codec_tag_string=MJPG
codec_tag=0x47504a4d
width=640
height=480
coded_width=640
coded_height=480
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
display_aspect_ratio=N/A
pix_fmt=yuvj422p
level=-99
color_range=pc
color_space=bt470bg
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=center
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=1000000/33333
avg_frame_rate=1000000/33333
time_base=33333/1000000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=150
duration=4.999950
bit_rate=9739922
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=150
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:Make=FUJIFILM
TAG:Model=FinePix JX550
TAG:DateTime=2012:05:20 00:25:48
TAG:JPEGInterchangeFormat=    658
TAG:JPEGInterchangeFormatLength=   2698
TAG:Copyright=    
TAG:DateTimeOriginal=2012:05:20 00:25:48
TAG:DateTimeDigitized=2012:05:20 00:25:48
TAG:MakerNote=
 uwu
TAG:title=FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0100
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=pcm_u8
codec_long_name=PCM unsigned 8-bit
profile=unknown
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/11024
codec_tag_string=[1][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0001
sample_fmt=u8
sample_rate=11024
channels=1
channel_layout=unknown
bits_per_sample=8
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/11024
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=88192
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=55120
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=0
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=DSCF0421.AVI
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=avi
format_long_name=AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)
start_time=0.000000
duration=4.999950
size=6111800
bit_rate=9778977
probe_score=100
[/FORMAT]
```

Then I tried [restoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706049/converting-video-formats-and-copying-tags-with-ffmpeg) it with either `.mp4` or `.mkv`

```
MP4

ffmpeg -i DSCF0421.AVI -i output.txt compressed.mp4

MKV

ffmpeg -i DSCF0421.AVI -i output.txt compressed.mkv
```

result of the command above:

MP4

```
C:\Users\PandaLabs\Desktop\Conversion underground>ffmpeg -i DSCF0421.AVI -i output.txt compressed.mp4
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-22-38490cb Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200513
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 46.100 / 56. 46.100
  libavcodec     58. 86.101 / 58. 86.101
  libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 82.100 /  7. 82.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'DSCF0421.AVI':
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9778 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 9739 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      Make            : FUJIFILM
      Model           : FinePix JX550
      DateTime        : 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      JPEGInterchangeFormat:     658
      JPEGInterchangeFormatLength:    2698
      Copyright       :
      DateTimeOriginal: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      DateTimeDigitized: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      MakerNote       :
                      :  70,  85,  74,  73,  70,  73,  76,  77,  12,   0,   0,   0,  18,   0,   0,   0
                      :   7,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0,  48,  49,  51,  48,  16,   0,   2,   0,  33,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0,  16,   2,   0,   8,   0,   0,   0,  35,   1
                      :   0,   0,   1,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   3,   0,   0,   0,   2,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  16,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,  17,  16,  10,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,  43,   1
                      :   0,   0,  32,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  33,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  49,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,  17,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  18
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  20
                      :   7,   0, 129,   0,   0,   0,  52,   1,   0,   0,  49,  20,   4,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,  53,  57,  50,  68,  51,  49,  51,  49,  51,  57,  51,  54,  51,  49
                      :  49,  50,  48,  51,  49,  56,  70,  70,  69,  53,  50,  83,  80,  48,  52,  54
                      :  50,  54,   0,  78,  79,  82,  77,  65,  76,  32,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 100
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
      title           : FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0100
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11024 Hz, mono, u8, 88 kb/s
Input #1, tty, from 'output.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 46 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: ansi, pal8, 640x400, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0000017c4ae758c0] Too many bits 6408.707483 > 6144 per frame requested, clamping to max
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'compressed.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      Make            : FUJIFILM
      Model           : FinePix JX550
      DateTime        : 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      JPEGInterchangeFormat:     658
      JPEGInterchangeFormatLength:    2698
      Copyright       :
      DateTimeOriginal: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      DateTimeDigitized: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      MakerNote       :
                      :  70,  85,  74,  73,  70,  73,  76,  77,  12,   0,   0,   0,  18,   0,   0,   0
                      :   7,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0,  48,  49,  51,  48,  16,   0,   2,   0,  33,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0,  16,   2,   0,   8,   0,   0,   0,  35,   1
                      :   0,   0,   1,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   3,   0,   0,   0,   2,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  16,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,  17,  16,  10,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,  43,   1
                      :   0,   0,  32,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  33,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  49,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,  17,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  18
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  20
                      :   7,   0, 129,   0,   0,   0,  52,   1,   0,   0,  49,  20,   4,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,  53,  57,  50,  68,  51,  49,  51,  49,  51,  57,  51,  54,  51,  49
                      :  49,  50,  48,  51,  49,  56,  70,  70,  69,  53,  50,  83,  80,  48,  52,  54
                      :  50,  54,   0,  78,  79,  82,  77,  65,  76,  32,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 100
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
      title           : FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0100
      encoder         : Lavc58.86.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 11025 Hz, mono, fltp, 66 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.86.101 aac
[mjpeg @ 0000017c4ae70fc0] mjpeg_decode_dc: bad vlc: 0:0 (0000017c4ae71688)
[mjpeg @ 0000017c4ae70fc0] error dc
[mjpeg @ 0000017c4ae70fc0] error y=59 x=39
frame=  150 fps=104 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2327kB time=00:00:05.01 bitrate=3801.3kbits/s speed=3.49x
video:2290kB audio:33kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.175157%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] frame I:2     Avg QP:25.35  size: 24876
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] frame P:38    Avg QP:26.87  size: 18472
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] frame B:110   Avg QP:27.42  size: 14477
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  2.7%  0.0% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] mb I  I16..4:  0.2% 98.9%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] mb P  I16..4:  0.2% 54.8%  1.2%  P16..4: 29.1% 11.2%  3.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] mb B  I16..4:  0.0% 22.9%  0.1%  B16..8: 40.5% 14.0%  3.0%  direct:15.2%  skip: 4.3%  L0:45.5% L1:42.5% BI:12.0%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] 8x8 transform intra:98.6% inter:79.9%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 92.1% 99.0% 74.7% inter: 60.8% 91.7% 25.7%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26%  7% 12% 55%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 10% 40%  6%  6%  6%  5%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 11% 19% 10%  9% 10%  6%  8%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] i8c dc,h,v,p: 65%  7% 23%  5%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.6% UV:2.6%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] ref P L0: 41.3% 11.9% 27.9% 18.5%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] ref B L0: 75.4% 19.4%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] ref B L1: 89.4% 10.6%
[libx264 @ 0000017c4ae65440] kb/s:3750.61
[aac @ 0000017c4ae758c0] Qavg: 27095.141
```

MKV

```
C:\Users\PandaLabs\Desktop\Conversion underground>ffmpeg -i DSCF0421.AVI -i output.txt compressed.mkv
ffmpeg version git-2020-05-22-38490cb Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200513
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 46.100 / 56. 46.100
  libavcodec     58. 86.101 / 58. 86.101
  libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 82.100 /  7. 82.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'DSCF0421.AVI':
  Duration: 00:00:05.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9778 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline) (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 9739 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      Make            : FUJIFILM
      Model           : FinePix JX550
      DateTime        : 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      JPEGInterchangeFormat:     658
      JPEGInterchangeFormatLength:    2698
      Copyright       :
      DateTimeOriginal: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      DateTimeDigitized: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      MakerNote       :
                      :  70,  85,  74,  73,  70,  73,  76,  77,  12,   0,   0,   0,  18,   0,   0,   0
                      :   7,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0,  48,  49,  51,  48,  16,   0,   2,   0,  33,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0,  16,   2,   0,   8,   0,   0,   0,  35,   1
                      :   0,   0,   1,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   3,   0,   0,   0,   2,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  16,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,  17,  16,  10,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,  43,   1
                      :   0,   0,  32,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  33,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  49,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,  17,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  18
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  20
                      :   7,   0, 129,   0,   0,   0,  52,   1,   0,   0,  49,  20,   4,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,  53,  57,  50,  68,  51,  49,  51,  49,  51,  57,  51,  54,  51,  49
                      :  49,  50,  48,  51,  49,  56,  70,  70,  69,  53,  50,  83,  80,  48,  52,  54
                      :  50,  54,   0,  78,  79,  82,  77,  65,  76,  32,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 100
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
      title           : FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0100
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 11024 Hz, mono, u8, 88 kb/s
Input #1, tty, from 'output.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 46 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: ansi, pal8, 640x400, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] profile High 4:2:2, level 3.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] 264 - core 159 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'compressed.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      Make            : FUJIFILM
      Model           : FinePix JX550
      DateTime        : 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      JPEGInterchangeFormat:     658
      JPEGInterchangeFormatLength:    2698
      Copyright       :
      DateTimeOriginal: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      DateTimeDigitized: 2012:05:20 00:25:48
      MakerNote       :
                      :  70,  85,  74,  73,  70,  73,  76,  77,  12,   0,   0,   0,  18,   0,   0,   0
                      :   7,   0,   4,   0,   0,   0,  48,  49,  51,  48,  16,   0,   2,   0,  33,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   1,   0,   0,   0,  16,   2,   0,   8,   0,   0,   0,  35,   1
                      :   0,   0,   1,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   3,   0,   0,   0,   2,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  16,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,   0,   0,   0,  17,  16,  10,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,  43,   1
                      :   0,   0,  32,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  33,  16
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  49,  16,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,  17,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  18
                      :   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   1,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   2,  19,   3,   0,   1,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,  48,  20
                      :   7,   0, 129,   0,   0,   0,  52,   1,   0,   0,  49,  20,   4,   0,   1,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,  53,  57,  50,  68,  51,  49,  51,  49,  51,  57,  51,  54,  51,  49
                      :  49,  50,  48,  51,  49,  56,  70,  70,  69,  53,  50,  83,  80,  48,  52,  54
                      :  50,  54,   0,  78,  79,  82,  77,  65,  76,  32,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 100
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
                      :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0
      title           : FUJIFILM AVI STREAM 0100
      encoder         : Lavc58.86.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 11024 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.86.101 libvorbis
[mjpeg @ 000002b3674f0fc0] mjpeg_decode_dc: bad vlc: 0:0 (000002b3674f1688)
[mjpeg @ 000002b3674f0fc0] error dc
[mjpeg @ 000002b3674f0fc0] error y=59 x=39
frame=  150 fps= 95 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2317kB time=00:00:04.99 bitrate=3797.5kbits/s speed=3.16x
video:2290kB audio:19kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:3kB muxing overhead: 0.355840%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] frame I:2     Avg QP:25.35  size: 24876
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] frame P:38    Avg QP:26.87  size: 18472
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] frame B:110   Avg QP:27.42  size: 14477
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] consecutive B-frames:  1.3%  2.7%  0.0% 96.0%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] mb I  I16..4:  0.2% 98.9%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] mb P  I16..4:  0.2% 54.8%  1.2%  P16..4: 29.1% 11.2%  3.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 0.1%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0% 22.9%  0.1%  B16..8: 40.5% 14.0%  3.0%  direct:15.2%  skip: 4.3%  L0:45.5% L1:42.5% BI:12.0%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] 8x8 transform intra:98.6% inter:79.9%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 92.1% 99.0% 74.7% inter: 60.8% 91.7% 25.7%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26%  7% 12% 55%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 12% 10% 40%  6%  6%  6%  5%  7%  8%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 22% 11% 19% 10%  9% 10%  6%  8%  5%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 65%  7% 23%  5%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.6% UV:2.6%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] ref P L0: 41.3% 11.9% 27.9% 18.5%  0.4%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] ref B L0: 75.4% 19.4%  5.2%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] ref B L1: 89.4% 10.6%
[libx264 @ 000002b3674f3f40] kb/s:3750.61
```

It doesn't successfully restore the metadata of the source `.AVI`

BTW, I don't intend to shrink the size of the video I just need to retain its created date and some miscellaneous.

Thank you in advance for those who will answer!

Comment: What are the exact metadata you want to copy?

Comment: @Ilogan, it's the 

`TAG:DateTimeOriginal=2012:05:20 00:25:48 || TAG:DateTimeDigitized=2012:05:20 00:25:48`

only. But it would be great if I can copy all of them.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i DSCF0421.AVI -t 1 compressed.mkv` Did it save the metadata tags?

Comment: Thank you very much Ilogan but it doesn't preserve the creation date.